# Error while importing SQLAlchemy class from flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: module

from flask import Flask

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLALchemy

app = Flask(**name**)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://username@localhost:5432/table'

db = SQLALchemy(app)

**error:**

ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLALchemy' from 'flask_sqlalchemy' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py

Comment: You have to write the module name correctly: `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

Comment: Note that you capitalised the l in Alchemy...